# Jsonreader parse error

Tags: java, android, json, jsonreader

I have a the following code:

```
reader = new JsonReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
```

It returns the following JSON:

```
{
  "results": [
    {
      "bioguide_id": "D000626",
      "in_office": true,
      "thomas_id": "02296",
      "govtrack_id": "412675",
      "crp_id": "N00038767",
      "fec_ids": [
        "H6OH08315"
      ],
      "first_name": "Warren",
      "nickname": null,
      "last_name": "Davidson",
      "middle_name": null,
      "name_suffix": null,
      "gender": "M",
      "birthday": "1970-03-01",
      "leadership_role": null,
      "term_start": "2016-06-09",
      "term_end": "2017-01-03",
      "state": "OH",
      "state_name": "Ohio",
      "party": "R",
      "title": "Rep",
      "chamber": "house",
      "phone": "202-225-6205",
      "fax": null,
      "website": null,
      "office": "1011 Longworth House Office Building",
      "contact_form": null,
      "votesmart_id": 166760,
      "district": 8,
      "oc_email": null,
      "ocd_id": "ocd-division/country:us/state:oh/cd:8"
    },
    {
      "bioguide_id": "L000585",
      "in_office": true,
      "thomas_id": "02295",
      "govtrack_id": "412674",
      "crp_id": "N00037031",
      "fec_ids": [
        "H6IL18088"
      ],
      "first_name": "Darin",
      "nickname": null,
      "last_name": "LaHood",
      "middle_name": null,
      "name_suffix": null,
      "gender": "M",
      "birthday": "1968-07-05",
      "leadership_role": null,
      "term_start": "2015-09-17",
      "term_end": "2017-01-03",
      "state": "IL",
      "state_name": "Illinois",
      "party": "R",
      "title": "Rep",
      "chamber": "house",
      "phone": "202-225-6201",
      "fax": null,
      "website": "https://lahood.house.gov/",
      "office": "2464 Rayburn House Office Building",
      "contact_form": "https://lahood.house.gov/contact/email",
      "votesmart_id": 128760,
      "district": 18,
      "oc_email": "Rep.Lahood@opencongress.org",
      "twitter_id": "RepLaHood",
      "youtube_id": null,
      "facebook_id": "1499570210366431",
      "ocd_id": "ocd-division/country:us/state:il/cd:18"
    }
  ],
  "count": 538,
  "page": {
    "count": 2,
    "per_page": 2,
    "page": 1
  }
}
```

I parse the reader in the following way:

```
try {

    reader.beginObject();
    while (reader.hasNext()) {
        String name = reader.nextName();
        if (name.equals("results")){
            reader.beginArray();
            while (reader.hasNext()) {
                reader.beginObject();
                while (reader.hasNext()) {
                    String id = reader.nextName();
                    if(id.equals("birthday"))
                        Log.d("id", id);
                    else
                        reader.skipValue();
                }
            }
        }

        else {
            reader.skipValue();
        }
    }

}
catch (IOException e){
    Log.w("Error",e.getMessage());
}
```

I get the following error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: com.app.congress.congressapp, PID: 5095
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected a name but was STRING
   at android.util.JsonReader.nextName(JsonReader.java:390)
   at com.app.congress.congressapp.GetAllStates.onPostExecute(ByState.java:57)
   at com.app.congress.congressapp.GetAllStates.onPostExecute(ByState.java:30)
   at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:636)
   at android.os.AsyncTask.access$500(AsyncTask.java:177)
   at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:653)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
E/AndroidRuntime: Error reporting crash
android.os.DeadObjectException
   at android.os.BinderProxy.transactNative(Native Method)
   at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Binder.java:496)
   at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.handleApplicationCrash(ActivityManagerNative.java:4164)
   at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$UncaughtHandler.uncaughtException(RuntimeInit.java:89)
   at java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:693)
   at java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:690)
```

Is there is way to parse the Jsonreader in a different way? I want the values of fields like birthday, end_term, bioguide_id etc. Parsing it manually like this is difficult and I have to make many other API calls which may return different Json results then again I have to spend time parsing it. I tried to use BufferedReader but that gives an Out Of Memory error in case of large Json file return.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to parse JSON in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9605913/how-to-parse-json-in-android)

Comment: Its not a duplicate I think because I cannot use BufferedReader because it gives OutOfMemory for large Json returns.

Comment: That isn't the important piece. You get a string, you put it into a `new JSONObject`, and you start parsing

Comment: I feel like I have to edit this line...reader = new JsonReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));...can you please tell me how because earlier I was using BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream())); and it gave me out of memory issue

Comment: If you want to continue using the InputStream, you need to call `endObject()` and `endArray()` accordingly

Comment: @cricket_007..I want to use the JSONObject way you suggested can you please tell me how to convert this...new JsonReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()))...to a JSONObject??

Comment: If your string doesn't fit in memory, then I don't think you can. As you said, you tried, but it isn't working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look carefully at your code:

```
                        String id = reader.nextName();
                        if(id.equals("birthday"))
                            Log.d("id", id);
                        else
                            reader.skipValue();
```

When "birthday" is the property name, you don't consume the value, so on the next pass through the loop, you call `nextName()` but the parser is still on the value.

Use this instead:

```
                        String id = reader.nextName();
                        if(id.equals("birthday")) {
                            Log.d("id", id);
                            reader.nextString(); // or reader.skipValue()
                        } else {
                            reader.skipValue();
                        }
```

Also as comments have pointed out, you need to have a matching `endObject()` for each `beginObject()` and a matching `endArray()` for each `beginArray()`.

Comment: Thanks...the post is marked as a duplicate...how can I get it removed??

Comment: that code a/ does not compile and b/ would have surprising results if it didi.

Comment: @Anirban duplicate was suggested in comment, but Q is not marked as such, so no worries. :)

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are making network calls using `AsyncTask`. This is tedious and you can do a lot of very bad things(https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jtlRNNhane0) this way. You are much, much better of using libraries like OkHttp(Used by `HttpUrlConnection` under the hood), Retrofit, Volley, Picasso, etc. It not only reduces complexity but also is much faster than `AsyncTask`s in some situations(http://instructure.github.io/blog/2013/12/09/volley-vs-retrofit/).

Using a library like Retrofit means that you can use a `FactoryConverter` to convert JSON into your POJO automatically(No need to read it manually). All you need to do is create a POJO to match your JSON(http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/) and define the API interface and a callback and Retrofit will take care of the rest.

To use Retrofit with Gson converter add the following dependencies to your gradle build file:

```
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.0.2'
```

Here's a simple example of a Service class using a Gson converter to convert to a POJO:

First create an interface class to define your API calls:

```
public interface GitHubService {
  @GET("users/{user}/repos")
  Call<List<Repo>> listRepos(@Path("user") String user);
}
```

Then create an instance of it using (Implementation taken care of by Retrofit):

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
    .baseUrl("https://api.github.com")
    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
    .build();

GitHubService service = retrofit.create(GitHubService.class);
```

Then you make a call using:

```
Call<List<Repo>> repos = service.listRepos("octocat");
```

You get a POJO of your definition already converted from JSON.

Take a look the following resources to get a better hang of it:

https://square.github.io/retrofit/

https://github.com/square/retrofit/

IMO the best documentation of Retrofit: https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-getting-started-and-android-client

Comment: that's nice, but that does not answer the question.

Comment: "Parsing it manually like this is difficult and I have to make many other API calls which may return different Json results then again I have to spend time parsing it. I tried to use BufferedReader but that gives an Out Of Memory error in case of large Json file return." I was answering this..